Present simple for the future
I start my work next week vs I will start my work next week
To me there is no real difference just present simple highlights it is fixed not really changeable. Corrrect?

Yes, we can use the present simple in the OP’s example.

I start my work next week.

British Council explains:

When we know about the future, we normally use the present tense.


We use the present simple for something scheduled:


We have a lesson next Monday.



I start my work next week.

indicates something  scheduled or agreed to or planned.

I will start my work next week.

can indicate the same (though the simple present is far more likely when that is the intended meaning), but it can also express mere intention, or firm resolution, or even procrastination.

The core meaning is the same, but there may be a difference of emphasis.

I start my work next week.

The present tense points to this moment. As I speak, I have a job.

I will start my work next week.

Here the future tense is used, so the focus is on the starting point. I have a definite job, but I don't start until next week. Compare I will start my work tomorrow.
So the point here, as so often, is that both tenses are valid, but they imply different meanings. It's not about the right tense, but about choosing the tense that matches what you want to say.
